# cannot access Component controller variables inside the component view

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have been running into this very weird issue with Laravel.

I had a problem where one of my component views was not able to read the variables defined in its class. It was kind of strange because I have several components running in my project and they all worked fine, except for this one.

So I created a fresh Laravel project to test some things out (Wanted to check if the problem was on my end, maybe I somehow messed up the project files).

I created a new component on a blank project using php artisan make:component top_nav
pre function basically is used as print_r which is in helper.php
Then I simply added a sql_data variable to the class component like so:[image][image][image: error image also is in there kindly help me]

i tried many thing as much as i can do but still i can't access that variable
also clear cache of view
of laravel
change name of components but still can't work

kindly help me..........

Answer (score 1):

you should

```
return view('components.top_nav', ['sql_data' => $sql_data]);
```

you are not passing the variable to the view

Comment: I also did that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`composer install`

`npm install && npm run dev`

`php artisan optimize`

I just copied your screenshots into a new laravel installation and ran it with no problems.

Try setting the public property with a default value:
`public $sql_data = 'testing'`

If you try the above and still have issues, I'd like to confirm the output of `AdminLogin::all()`.

PS:
`TopNav` instead of `top_nav` Class name please.

Comment: ok, but it works when I use an inline component 
thanks for your help